# Find the integral by interpreting the integral in terms of sums and/or differences of areas of elementary figures.

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Problem**: You are given the four points in the plane $A=(2,−5)$, $B=(7,1)$, $C=(12,−7)$, and $D=(14,1)$. The graph of the function $f(x)$ consists of the three line segments AB, BC and CD. Find the integral $\int_2^{14} f(x) dx$ by interpreting the integral in terms of sums and/or differences of areas of elementary figures.

I understand that I need to find the slopes of AB, BC and CD using $m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. I've recently studied Integration, Integration by substitution and Integration by parts. How do I use the slopes to $\int_2^{14} f(x) dx$ ? I don't understand how to apply it.

Any tips would help, if this pisses you off, please move on.

Comment: Do you know the formula which gives the area of a trapeze.

Comment: The area of a triangle (or a trapezoid) is not especially  easy to express in terms of the slopes of its sides, but rather in terms of the *lengths* of its sides.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah it's $A = ½ (a + b) h$, could I use the trapezoidal rule on this?

Comment: While the trapezoidal rule will give you the correct answer, understand that it is intended for approximating integrals, not giving the exact value. Thus if you are expected to justify your answer, you will need to add an explaination as to why in this particular case it gives an exact answer, not the usual approximation.

Answer (score 1):

As we know, integral can be interpretted as a net area under the curve, so as you are asked in the question, you just need to carefully decompose $f(x)$ into elementary figures and then compute their areas.

In your example, it would seem to be logical to write the integral as
$$
\int_2^{14} f(x)dx = \int_2^{7} f(x)dx + \int_7^{12} f(x)dx + \int_{12}^{14} f(x)dx
$$
since these are exactly the line segments between 4 points. However, we can note that $f(x)$ changes its sign three times, which is important for us since the integral is a **net** area. So more convenient way would be to first find zeroes of $f(x)$ and then divide the segment $[2, 14]$ according to these zeroes.

First zero clearly is between 2 and 7. Since the slope of the line between A and B is $(1-(-5))/(7-2) = 6/5$, we find that $f(x) = 0$ when $y = 6x/5 + -7.4, y = 0$, so $x = 37/6$.

Similarly, the second zero is between 7 and 12, on that segment $f(x)$ can be written as $y = -8x/5+12.2$, so $f(x) = 0$ when $x = 61/8$.

Finally, the third zero is between 12 and 14, on that segment $f(x)$ can be written as $y = 4x-55$, so $f(x) = 0$ when $x = 55/4$.

Now we can write
$$
\int_2^{14} f(x)dx = \int_2^{37/6} f(x)dx + \int_{37/6}^{61/8} f(x)dx + \int_{61/8}^{55/4} f(x)dx + \int_{55/4}^{1} f(x)dx
$$
and note that each of these four integrals represents an area of a triangle, which can easily be computed. Namely, on $[2, 37/6]$ the height is $-5$ (y-coordinate of the point A) while the length is $37/6-2 = 25/6$, thus the area is $-5*25/6*1/2 = -125/12$. Doing the same operations with other parts we will get areas $1 * (61/8-37/6) * 1/2 = 35/48$, $-7 * (55/4-61/8) * 1/2 = -343/16$ and $1 * (14 - 55/4) * 1/2 = 1/8$, so the total area would be $-125/12+35/48-343/16+1/8 = -31$.